# BannerAd should be place in Fragment container or in Fragment's layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, ads

My app is pretty simple: it uses one activity and switches fragments in a fragment container (a `FrameLayout`).

I'm wondering if I should either have the banner ad as a static view below the fragment container (so that it's independent of whatever fragment is visible), or if I should place the ad within each fragment view, so that I request and display a new ad with each fragment.  What makes sense from a monetary perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways it's fine and its completely up to you, though I use it in `FrameLayout` because sometimes when user launches the fragment and there is no internet connection and it means no Ad for that session while if its integrated in `FrameLayout` then it will still have it form previous session.